# Comprehensive list of GLIBC functions that can execute a file (execv, execve, fexecve, posix_spawn,..)

Tags: fork, exec, glibc, libc

I am writing an LD_PRELOAD utility that wraps all calls to exec() type functions.

But holy cow, there are a lot of them.  So far I have found:

execv, execvp, execve, execvpe
fexecve, execveat,
execl, execlp, execle, execlpe,
posix_spawn, posix_spawnp

Is there a comprehensive list somewhere of all the lib functions that execute another program (and aren't just wrappers to one of these functions)?

As an example, I just discovered that whatever the perl library IPC::Open3 uses is not on the list above, so I don't see the exec that happens.  (strace sees it, but it claims that everything on the list above is just 'execve' which is not actually true.)

Comment: From your perspective, does `dlopen` execute a file or not?

Comment: Great question - I'll say no for now.  I'm interested in any executables that are run as opposed to opening shared libraries and running that code.

Answer (score 0):

At least on my (Debian GNU/Linux) system, the `execve` system call comes from `Perl` calling `execvp`:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7d35787 in execve () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:120
#1  0x00007ffff7d3603b in __execvpe_common (file=0x5555559ee710 "some", argv=0x5555558e31f0, envp=0x5555558c6980, exec_script=<optimized out>) at execvpe.c:136
#2  0x00005555556bcf50 in Perl_do_aexec5 ()
#3  0x00005555556b14ef in Perl_pp_exec ()
#4  0x0000555555652cf6 in Perl_runops_standard ()
#5  0x00005555555c6a6c in perl_run ()
#6  0x000055555559c472 in main ()
(gdb) fr 2

#2  0x00005555556bcf50 in Perl_do_aexec5 ()
(gdb) x/i $pc-5
   0x5555556bcf4b <Perl_do_aexec5+427>: callq  0x55555559b2c0 <execvp@plt>
```

Using `ltrace` also confirms that:

```
ltrace -f --library=libc.so.6  perl foo.pl |& grep execv
[pid 1789012] perl->execvp(0x55cd3c4a4bc0, 0x55cd3c3a28e0, 0x7fff82e61770, 0x7fd4f3317212) = 0xffffffff
...
```

Comment: That's interesting.  I see that it calls execvp in my example, but if I catch execvp with LD_PRELOAD, I don't see it for the open3 (though I do see it for a perl system() call).

So maybe there are two questions - the first is what is the comprehensive list, and the second is why does my LD_PRELOAD catch perl system() but not open3??